# Limiting threads with Semaphore

Tags: c, client-server, semaphore

Having trouble understanding the theory behind semaphores. I have a thread client-server application and I want to use semaphores to limit the amount of threads (clients) to 30. I am having trouble understanding sem_wait and sem_post and how to implement them with the 30 limit. Some insight and examples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if a semaphore is a good idea here.  Typically, if a server<>client thread finds it cannot proceed because of some limit, it returms a 'Server busy - try again later' message to the client. A seamphore limit would block the server<>client thread until a unit became available, by which time the client may well have timed out anyway :(

Comment: @MartinJames How should I go about limiting the threads then?

Comment: I would probably use an atomic integer, init to 0.  After a successful accept(), check it against the limit value and, if less, count it up and create a server<>client thread to service the socket in the usual way, if more, issue an immediate 'Busy' message to the client socket from the accept() thread, then close the client socket and don't bother creating a client<>server thread.  Count it down whenever a client<>server thread is about to close its client socket and exit.